# Singer-IO JIRA tap - Not getting records

Tags: etl, jira-rest-api, singer-io, meltano

I am getting only Projects and Versions Stream RECORDS only; Catalog(properties.json) contain 11 streams.

How to get other Streams RECORDS also? I run this command:

```
tap-jira -c config.json -p properties.json > finaloutput.json
```

My `properties.json` is here:

[properties.json](https://github.com/singer-io/tap-jira/blob/01d1668bf71ac4ceabd0b29edf09ec49e098d377/spikes/issues-fields-envelope-unwrapping/tap_files/properties.json)

Answer (score 0):

I think the sync command is the following:

```
tap --config config.json --catalog properties.json
```

according to the [sync doc](https://github.com/singer-io/getting-started/blob/master/docs/SYNC_MODE.md)

Actually this works for me through meltano orchestration.

And I suppose you got the *properties.json* using:

```
tap --config config.json --discover > properties.json
```

[discovery doc](https://github.com/singer-io/getting-started/blob/master/docs/DISCOVERY_MODE.md#discovery-mode)